# How to persist UWSGI server on AWS after console closed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm a newcomer to web applications and AWS, so please forgive me if this is the answer is bit trivial!

I'm hosting a python web application on a AWS EC2 server using nginx + uWSGI. This is all working perfectly, except when I terminate my connection (using putty), my uWSGI application stops running, producing a "502 Bad Gateway" error from nginx.

I'm aware of adding the "&" to the uwsgi start up command (below), but that does not work after I close out my connection.

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8000 -master -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock --chmod-socket=666 -w wsgi2 &
```

How do I persist my uWSGI application to continue hosting my web app after I log out/terminate my connection?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of my use case, I will not have to reboot my machine in the near future, so Linux's nohup (no hangup) command works perfectly for this. It's a quick and dirty hack that's super powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically want to start uwsgi from an init script.  There are several ways to do this and the exact procedure depends on the Linux distribution you're using:

1. SystemV init script
2. upstart script (Ubuntu)
3. supervisor (Python-based process manager)

Comment: any you recommend for Red Hat 7?

Comment: Nothing specific.  I'm not familiar with Red Hat 7, but use whatever init system it comes with.